# How to Upload an Image to Server by Using UnityWebRequest

Tags: c#, http, unity-game-engine

I am trying to upload image with `MultipartFormFileSection` which is giving me Http 500 Internal Server Error.

```
 IEnumerator Upload()
{
    List<IMultipartFormSection> pictureData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();

    pictureData.Add(new MultipartFormFileSection("file", File.ReadAllBytes(ImageCapture.imageSavePath), "imageName", "image/jpg"));
    pictureData.Add(new MultipartFormFileSection("userId", "17ac4c482dcdd"));

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(UploadImage_URL, pictureData);

    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete! " + www.downloadHandler.text);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons unknown to me, it worked by replacing `MultipartFormFileSection` with `WWWForm`.

Below is the working code.

```
IEnumerator Upload()
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddBinaryData("file", File.ReadAllBytes(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/test.jpg"), "imageName.jpg");
    form.AddField("userId", "17ac4c482dcdd");

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(UploadImage_URL, form);

    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete! " + www.downloadHandler.text);

    }
}
```

Comment: Strange indeed. As you can see in the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) for the `MultipartFormSection` overload it automatically chooses `Content-Type = multipart/form-data` while for the `WWWForm` overload it uses the one defined in the [`WWWForm`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm-headers.html) which is `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" for normal forms and "multipart/form-data" for forms containing data added using AddBinaryData.` so it should be the same, right?

Comment: yes you are right. In my previous projec I used `MultipartFormSection` and it worked. But this time I need to add few fields, ID and Name, so it starts giving error.